# Ошибка при попытке вставить дату в ms sql

Tags: c#, sql-server

Формирую команду на вставку данных в ms sql сервер используя `SqlCommand`

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(comm, conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

И выходит ошибка -

> преобразование varchar в datetime привело к выходу за пределы
>   диапазона.

Как я понимаю из-за формата даты (месяц и день перепутаны). Есть ли универсальный способ вставки? Просто заранее не известно какой формат будет на сервере и какой в xml.

ubdate: структуру бд создаю тоже с помощью `SqlCommand` и для столбца указываю тип данных `datetime`, но получается что он принимает гггг дд мм

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что сейчас вы передаете дату как строчку в SQL. И не угадываете с форматом.

Откажитесь от преобразования даты на уровне SQL. Преобразовывайте строчку кодом на C#, и спускайте в `SqlCommand` в виде параметра с типом `DateTime`, а не `string`:

```
DateTime dateValue = DateTime.Parse("ваша строка", "конкретный формат",
                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

comm = "INSERT INTO ... (...) VALUES (..., @SomeDateValue)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(comm, conn);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SomeDateValue", dateValue);
```

Сейчас же, судя по коду, вы вообще собираете непараметризованный SQL. Это PHP-style, с соответствующими проблемами и ошибками (первую из которых вы уже поймали).

Comment: а если все сделать `varchar` ? или это не вариант ?

Comment: @e1s даже если сделать varchar - все равно стоит значения параметрами, а не склейкой SQL. ну и выборки по этому столбцу делать нормально не получится.

Comment: те надо все через параметры передавать? или это только для дат характерно?

Comment: @e1s все через параметры. иначе намучаетесь с эскейпингом строчек - если у вас доверенный источник данных. или сделаете позорную дырку с sql injection - если источник недоверенный.

Answer (score 3):

Формат `YYYYMMDD` поддерживается всегда и везде и не зависит от локали и прочих настроек. В SQL должен использоваться только он. Если исходный формат иной, то преобразуйте его к универсальному, а не мучайтесь с локалями.

Примечание: формат `YYYY-MM-DD` (с дефисами) всё-таки зависит от настроек.

Впрочем, я бы порекомендовал строить запросы с помощью ORM, а не генерировать строчки вручную. Тогда эти проблемы вообще не будут вас волновать.

Comment: в том то и дело что в xml в данном формате, но 2014-01-28 выбрасывает это исключение. БД создаю вручную в конструкторе ms sql

Comment: @e1s Попробуйте без дефисов.

Answer (score 0):

Универсального способа нет, например чему по вашему соответствует `10.11.12`, поэтому вам придется определять отдельно локальные настройки сервера, файлов и так далее. Но во многих случаях можно воспользоваться конструкцией:

```
CAST('YYYY-MM-DD' as datetime)
```

или

```
CONVERT(datetime, 'YYYY-MM-DD', 102)
```

Если сервер не настроен на уж что-то совсем экзотическое, должно помочь.